# How to divide $n$ distinct elements into $k$ groups of size of at least $m$

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I have never been good with combinatorics, so I have always stuck with memorizing the formula. However, I can't even begin to fathom the complexity of this problem.

I have tried searching for helpful answers on this site, but I only found " $n$ identical elements into groups of size at least $k$ " and " $n$ distinct elements into $k$ nonempty groups.

I have also read about the Stirling numbers, but I did not see anything about the size of the groups.

I would appreciate if someone could help me approach this problem, or direct me to an already posted question if this is a repost, for which I apologize in advance.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My question is in the title of this post. "How can I divide 'n' distinct elements into 'k' groups of size of at least 'm'?"

Comment: Taking the title of your question literally, here's how I'd start: find the binomial coefficient (often `nchoosek` in programming languages) $\binom{n}{m}$. If this is greater than $k$, then you know you can divide the set into $k$ groups of size $m$ and you're done (well, you know it's possible, then you figure out how to make those groups). But if $\binom{n}{m} < k$, see if $\binom{n}{m} + \binom{n}{m + 1} \geq k$, and keep adding larger and larger sizes until you get a set of groups exceeding $k$. Does this help?

Comment: My approach to "figuring out h ow to make those groups" would be to do {($n$ choose $m$) choose $k$}, although I'm not sure if that is correct. Furthermore, isn't binomial coefficient for indiscriminate elements? I have distinct elements, so should I not be doing something with permutation?

Comment: @Skipher Please put your question in the question body.  Also, what you are asking is not at all clear to me.  Do want to do the division?  Or do you want to count the number of such divisions?  Are there any restrictions beside $n\ge mk$?  Are the groups distinguished?  That is is putting item 1 in group 1 and item 2 in group 2 different from putting item 2 in group 1 and item 1 in group 2?

Comment: I apologize for not explicitly writing the question in the body of the post. Yes, I am trying to count the number of such divisions, and yes, the $k$ groups are distinguishable. Also, there are no additional restrictions than $n$ $\ge$ $mk$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're okay with the exponential formula  for set partitions (say, in [Wilf's Generatingfunctionology book](https://www.math.upenn.edu/%7Ewilf/gfology2.pdf), section 3.6), then the mixed generating function $$H(x,y)=\sum_{n,k} h(n,k) \frac{x^n}{n!}y^k$$ for the number of ways $h(n,k)$ to divide $n$ distinguishable elements into $k$ groups of size at least $m$ is
$$H(x,y)=e^{y(e^x - e_{<m}^x)},$$ where $e_{<m}^x=\sum_{p<m}\frac{x^p}{p!}$. Then, by extracting the coefficient of $y^k$ in $H(x,y)$ you get$$ h(n,k)=n![x^n]\left(\frac{(e^x - e_{<m}^x)^k}{k!}\right).$$ It looks like you won't get anything pretty, but for any $m$ and $k$ you can expand $(e^x - e_{<m}^x)^k$ with the multinomial theorem and then extract the coefficient of $x^n$ to get an explicit value.